# Resize view while ActionBar slide up animation is running

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation, onmeasure

I have an ImageView inside an activity and when the user clicks on it, I animate the view height so it becomes fullscreen (other views are just become hidden below the bottom of the screen).

However once the animation is finished I hide the actionbar (using `getSupportActionBar().hide()`) so I then need to resize my ImageView just a little bigger again to take the full screen again.
In the parent View I tried overriding both `onMeasure` and `onLayout` to get the size available while the actionbar slides off the screen, but it does not work, I only get the new size at the end of the actionbar animation + when I set the height of the view and request layout it does not layout again (so I can still see the other views at the bottom of the screen).

Answer (score 3):

Make the `ActionBar` an overlay by calling `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY)` before calling `setContentView()` in your activity. Then when you run your animation, the full-screen size of the `ImageView` will go behind the `ActionBar`.

You might have to mess with the timing of when to hide the `ActionBar` if you don't want the `ImageView` to be seen behind it at all before you hide, but that can be done relatively easily with a `Thread` or `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is I don't want the ActionBar to be in overlay mode.

Comment: Or is it possible to make the ActionBar switch from non-overlay to overlay mode programatically while the activity is already launched?

Comment: Not that I know of. You have to set the feature before calling `setContentView`.